# Django Path To Resource Failure?

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, drf-queryset

When I try a GET request on one of my API endpoints it can't find the endpoint.

[image: Why is this happening, shouldn't it match?]

urls.py file looks like this

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib import admin
from api.resources import NoteResource

note_resource = NoteResource()

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include(note_resource.urls)),
]
```

api.resources looks like this

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from api.models import Note

class NoteResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Note.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'note'
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Solution: It appears that `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/note/` works properly.. why would this be?

Comment: You have backslash `/` at the end of your `path`. Have you tried `127.0.0.1:8000/api/` ?

Comment: can you add NoteResource too?

Comment: @SijanBhandari still the 404 error with / at the end

Comment: @JishnunandPk just added it!

Comment: You server is running at `8000`, right? Does `127.0.0.1:8000/admin` working?

Comment: @SijanBhandari yes `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin` works properly

Comment: @SijanBhandari it appears that when I use `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/note/` it works properly.. any idea why that is?

Comment: Why have you tagged this as DRF when you are using tastypie?

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes

Comment: Is that helpful @JohnFisher ?

Comment: Yes thank you for the help

Comment: @JohnFisher you need to mark the answer as approved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also have one url entry in `note_resource.urls` for only `/api` request. Something similar to

`path('api/', APIClass)`.

But, you never need that endpoint. Because, `/api` does not represent any actual request in your system.

I rather suggest to have following endpoints :

```
path('api/notes/',include(note_resource.urls))
```

in your main `urls.py`.

So that you can have multiple urls in main `urls.py` file representing each app.

```
 path('api/<APP_NAME>(s)/',include(<APP_NAME>.urls))
```

And, you will manage other endpoints in your `app urls.py` file:

# Create a new Note

```
path(
        'create/',
        NoteCreate.as_view()
    ),
```